# Add access control for Jekyll blog

Tags: jekyll, access-control

I built a blog with **Jekyll** , I write technical posts and something about my daily life. I want to make my technical posts available to anybody but posts about myself only available to my friends for privacy. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You may find useful the answer about oauth2_proxy at this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50809299/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-restrict-access-to-a-static-website-using-social-aut

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Jekyll itself, you can’t (barring some arcane JavaScript client-side encryption). You can use your webserver’s access control settings, though. If you use Apache, you can use the `.htaccess` file to [protect a certain folder with a password](https://davidwalsh.name/password-protect-directory-using-htaccess). And then you would need to set up Jekyll to output the protected posts into this folder only.

Comment: I checked the link [protect a certain folder with a password](https://davidwalsh.name/password-protect-directory-using-htaccess) , in fact the Apache server provides access control functionality right? The `.htaccess` file is part of that? I would go to read the Apache docs carefully...

Comment: Yes, the `.htaccess` file is an Apache configuration file, you can read about it [in the Apache docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html).